# Navigate from an embedded UICollectionView (inside a UIContainerView) to a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue, uicontainerview

I have a UICollectionView which is embedded into a UIContainerView. So I want to navigate from this embedded UICollectionView to an independent (not embedded) UIViewController but it throws an error. I know it should be pretty straightforward to use either a Segue or self.present etc. but in this situation it doesn't allow me to do it. Embedded CollectionView looks like the dead end. How can I navigate to a new UIViewController from an embedded CollectionView. Please see the image. Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as navigating from a View to a View Controller. It should be View Controller to View Controller. Don't try to take a segue from a View to a View Controller. Try to take it from the View Controller which has that UICollectionView.